# How to use HTTPBuilder behind a proxy with authentication

Tags: groovy, proxy, httpbuilder

I tried 2 hours and could not make it work.
This is what I did:

1. ```
   grails add-proxy myproxy "--host=<host>" "--port=<port>" "--username=<username>" "--password=<psw>"
   grails use-proxy myproxy
   ```

   I got connection refused error which mean the proxy is not working
2. In my groovy file, I add the proxy

   ```
   def http = new HTTPBuilder("http://http://headers.jsontest.com/")
   http.setProxy(host, port, "http");
   http.request(Method.GET, JSON) {
       uri.path = '/'
       response.success = { resp, json ->
                       .....
       }
   }
   ```

   I then get groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Proxy Authentication Required

I could not figure out how I set the user/psw for the proxy to make it work

I tried the java way, not working

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", username);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", password);
```

and

```
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, .toCharArray());
    }});
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it will work, but there's [some code over here](https://gist.github.com/bryanchug/4172603) that shows you should do:

```
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*
import org.apache.http.auth.*

def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://www.ipchicken.com'  )

http.client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
    new AuthScope("myproxy.com", 8080),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("proxy-username", "proxy-password")
)

http.setProxy('myproxy.com', 8080, 'http')

http.request( GET, TEXT ){ req ->
    response.success = { resp, reader ->
        println "Response: ${reader.text}"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not working, I guess it needs sth like setProxyCredentials instead. However, I could not figure out the API.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy authentication uses different HTTP header (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Proxy-Authorization), so simply adding the header should work for you.

```
String basicAuthCredentials = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(String.format("%s:%s", username,password).getBytes());
http.setHeaders(['Proxy-Authorization' : "Basic " + basicAuthCredentials])
```

Comment: P.S. It won't work for proxying https sites, as HTTPBuilder sends CONNECT request first